# connection string in application code c#

Tags: c#

instead of setting the connection string in the web.config file as seems to be best practice is there anything wrong with having this in the application code instead?
My web.config files contains clear text passwords and I dont think any of the method out there to encrypt will help me as I am using mono/nginx to host this site and not IIS.
Part of the project involves giving user access to the .aspx file to run some changes but I cant stop them from viewing the web.config file.  I perhaps could put the .aspx in another folder and then restrict, but the above may address my issue anyway

I am using MySQL

Comment: Okay, so you embed your connection string in the application code.  What happens if you want to use that same code against another database?  Do you understand that putting the connection string in the code does *not* protect that string?  Connection strings are in configuration files for a reason.

Comment: the whole point of having it in the config file, is that it could be configured without a recompile and update of the application. if you don't need that, you can as well include it in code. this is not usually done in practice, think of a software where you have a test system and a production system, you're using the same code and just point to a different database. or in a line-of-business context, admins would be mad if they could not adjust the config file whenever they relocate a database. encrypt the connection string: roll your own, so there is no plain text password at least.

Comment: Is there something like "Integrated Security" for MySQL on Mono? This would allow you to have a config without any user/pass.

Answer (score 1):

Put a plain string in the code is not safer than put in a web.config file, a because a compiled dll can be easier decompiled.

I suggest to remove all read permission from the config file except for web application.

I also suggest you to read this useful answer:
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/15055

Comment: "a compiled .dll can be easily decompiled?" - really I thought this was almost impossible

Comment: @AShah You thought incorrectly.  DLLs are easily decompiled.  Case in point, ILSpy is an application that exists explicitly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously, hard-coding the connection string in your application code means you'll need to re-compile and re-deploy the application if ever the connection string changes (e.g. a password change).

I understand your concern is related to the credentials being stored in clear text in the `web.config` file. Microsoft has this covered by allowing you to encrypt sections of the `web.config` file for this very reason.

This is documented on MSDN on the page '[Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)', as well as the following walkthrough: '[Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx)'.

This approach uses the `aspnet_regiis` utility to encrypt the `web.config` file. For example, the following command encrypts the `<ConnectionStrings>` section of the `web.config` file for the application named `MyApplication`:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApplication"
```

Check out the two links (particularly the second one) I've provided above to see how to customize this for your needs, and the code required to use it.

Comment: Good answer, but he is using nginx not IIS

Answer (score 0):

This is what I believe the best solution would be.

1. Create a MySQL user that only has exactly the permission to the table(s) that the page absolutely requires and only the access that is absolutely required. So for example if they only require select access to one table only give them exactly that.
2. you can either have the connection string in a another .cs file they do not have access to or you can read the connection string in for a "text" file that is out of the directory that the client does not have access 2.

The dis-advantage to either of the options is that they could print the value of the connection string during execution and get the password, that is why the first step is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

One mechanism that is often underrated, and might be useful to you, is the machine.config file.  There's a different machine.config file for each version of the .net framework at a static location on the hard drive of any machine with the .net framework installed, and if your web app doesn't find a config setting in its web.config file, it will automatically look for it in that machine's machine.config file as a fallback.  In the past I've taken advantage of this and moved connection strings out of the web.config and into the server's machine.config instead, and it works great without any code changes necessary.

Comment: @AShah is using mono, not .NET and probably neither Windows.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti Mono uses machine.config files as well.